# as3 comparing two arrays and returning index

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, compare, indexing

i want to create a function that compares 2 arrays and returns indexes of items found. if for examples my arrays are:

```
var distances:Array = new Array (0,275,217,385,275,0,251);
var selectedDist:Array = new Array (217,275,251);
```

i would like it to return 2,4,6

Comment: Why do you return index 4 for the distance 275? Why not just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var indices:Array = [];

for each(var distance:int in selectedDist) {
    var index:int = distances.indexOf(distance);
    if (index >= 0) {
        indices.push(index);
    }
}

return indices;
```

Comment: thank you..works great..except for indices:array.push(index), should have been indices.push(index)...cheers

Comment: Yes sorry, I typed the code directly here, so I didn't notice that. I am editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you would always compare **selectedDist array** to **distances array**, I would do that :

```
protected function compareArrays(arr1:Array, arr2:Array):Array
{
  var matches:Array = new Array();

  for(var x:int=0; x < arr2.length; x++) {
    /*
     * indexOf returns -1 id the element is not found in the array
     * http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf()
     * but you have to grab the lastIndexOf 275, as requested...
     */
     if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[x] > -1))
       matches.push(arr1.lastIndexOf(arr2[x]));
    }

    return matches;
}
```